# Is it possible to connect a shared repository checkpoint's value to a datatable value?

Tags: object, datatable, repository, qtp

I'm working with Quick Test Professional 11.

The situation is, i would like to keep my checkpoints also in a shared repository, but the checkpoints' property values are always different because the cases+values in the datatables are also different ones.

I know that i could set a datatable parameter for a local checkpoint, but this feature is not able for shared checkpoints, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using with the Global Data Table.....